# How to call Membership and Roles methods inside transaction?

Tags: asp.net, transactions, membership, roles

I have a method which calls Membership.UpdateUser() as well as some Roles methods along with some custom inserts, deletes of my own. Is it possible to do all this in a transaction? I don't see any way to associate a transaction with the Membership or Roles providers. To clarify,  I would like all operations to happen within the same transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your updates within a TransactionScope scope:

```
using (TransactionScope trans = new TransactionScope([option]))
{
    Membership.Provider.UpdateUser(...);
    Membership.Provider.UpdateUser(...);
    trans.Complete();
}
```

Comment: What a joy to discover this. So, if methods like Membership.CreateUser use their own transactions, the framework is smart enough to use the new one introduced in the block? And it seems no annoying try, catch, commit, rollback, blah, blah, blah is required.

Comment: Anything that uses an SQLDataProvider can be wrapped within a TransactionScope in this way.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx under remarks on how it determines whether it uses a new transaction.